# How to hide toolbar from product list page added on home CMS page magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

How to hide toolbar from product list page added on home CMS page magento2.

I have added block in CMS home as below:

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" category_id="3"}}
```

and added xml code to remove toolbar in Layout Update XML as below code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add to Layout Update XML this (use **display="false"** param instead of remove="true"):

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" display="false" />
```

then clean cache and toolbar should disappear

Comment: "Your answer certainly is worth a little explanation. Kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Comments would help create searchable content.
"

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar is being called in: `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Copy and paste that file to override it in your theme: `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Add this xml snippet:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="hide_toolbar" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
</arguments>
```

Find `echo $block->getToolbarHtml()` in the file you just created and do something like:

```
if ($this->getHideToolbar() === false) {
    echo $block->getToolbarHtml();
}
```

And it will no longer appear.